# Matrix Representation (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

$A:X \to X$. Find the matrix representation in the basis $\mathbb{R}^2=span{(1,3), (2,5)}$ for $A(x)=(2x_2,3x_1-x_2)$

I don't know how to find matrix representation. Someone can help me and show the solution? Thanks!!!

Comment: Consider [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/60099) when you wirte your question.

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If $a_1,a_2$ are the vectors of the basis, then

$$\begin{align}A(a_1)&=(6,0)=-30a_1+18a_2\\A(a2)&=(10,1)=-48a_1+29a_2\end{align}$$
So
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-30& -48\\\phantom{-}18& \phantom{-}29\end{bmatrix}$$

Is that right? Thanks!

Comment: No the images of basis vectors define the _columns_ of the matrix (once expressed in coordinates on the basis at arrival).